# How to export Excel to pdf with page size aligned with the printable area

Tags: microsoft-excel, print-to-pdf

I have a couple of rectangular tables with varying side ratios and I need to export them to pdf with the page size aligned with its content, something like 5 mm offset. So if I have a 20x10 cm table, I want the page size to be 21x11 cm.

Currently, I'm setting the page size manually, starting from a default size and iteratively adjusting the dimensions until I'm satisfied. That is both tedious and makes it difficult to delegate the spreadsheet to someone else.

Is there a way to have the page size adjust automatically upon export? Or at least a more efficient way than the one I'm currently using?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psQjL.jpg)

Comment: Are able to use VBA? If so, use the macro recorder to record what happens when you adjust the page size manually. That will help you identify the object or objects involved in page size adjustment. You'll then need to find a way of determining the dimensions of the tables you want to place in your pdf. Taking this approach would allow you to develop a VBA solution of your own.

Comment: I can use VBA, but it seems to come up short in this case. It can switch between available page sizes, so I can use it to switch from A4 format to "custom page size". However, setting the actual dimensions of the custom page size is a separate step that does not get recorded in the macro. I'm afraid this is more a matter of the printer driver, which I won't be able to influence from within Excel, but I really don't know. But thanks anyway, at least I wrote a method that gets the table size, so I don't have to guess iteratively anymore.